# Multiple PayPal Add to Cart buttons with their own checkout urls

Tags: paypal

Multiple PayPal Add to Cart buttons with their own checkout urls

So I have multiple PayPal `Add to Cart` buttons with their own (different) checkout urls (yeah don't ask me why, it just is). With multiple items in a shopper's cart which checkout urls will the payment be redirected to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the return URL of the last or first item added. Or perhaps none, since depending on how the payment is made at PayPal a receipt may be shown, and the user needs to click to return. Many could just close the window instead.

You are better off using a non-`Add to Cart` button integration that does not redirect away, also known as a Smart Button. Here is an example implementation: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , and there is a generator at https://www.paypal.com/buttons

---

If by chance you do end up putting multiple smart buttons on the same page, ensure the SDK script is only loaded once before the buttons are rendered, and that they are each rendered to their own unique id container div element.

Comment: I tried that but WordPress doesn't display the new smart button code for some reason?